# Download Resume Not Possible in Azure

Tags: file, azure, download, hosting

I have created a Storage>Blob>Container and added a file to it using an Explorer Tool.The problem is that the file download cannot be resumed,once paused 
The file needs to be downloaded from the starting.Is this feature not available on Azure

Comment: What tool are you using to perform the download?

Comment: I'd say that it's a failure on the tool as the Azure C# SDK provides starting from a specific byte position in the blob.

Comment: @MikeWo There is no tool needed,just download from the link normally

Comment: @siva.k This is the process of hosting a file for public download.No Tools Involved

Comment: That isn't supported in BLOB storage via the HTTP protocol but it is part of the REST API. The BLOB storage isn't meant for that type of access which is why the CDN layer exists, which does allow pausing and resuming downloads.

Comment: @siva.k I cannot see an option called CDN anywhere in storage

Comment: @techno It's not part of storage, it's a separate thing: https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/Cdn/Endpoints

The CDN sits in front of your blob storage and you point people through it. It offloads the public downloads from blob storage to network edge data centers that have a cached copy of the blob.

Comment: @siva.k I tried using the link you provided a page opened saying no cdn endpoint created and there was an option to create one,but after clicking on the create icon,the panel popped up with the option to create an azure service as normal but there was nothing saying CDN. Where exactly is the option for CDN

Comment: New (+) -> App Services -> CDN

Answer (score 0):

It must be a combination of BLOB storage and the software doing the downloading. I tested this by using Internet Explorer to pull down a public file in BLOB storage and paused it. When attempting to resume it simply restarted as @techno stated; however, when using Azure Management Studio I was able to pause and resume with no issues.

Also, when I used Chrome I could pause and resume download from the same file as used above, but not every time.  Sometimes it would restart.  The browsers are looking at the partially downloaded file in the temp folders they use and looking at the incoming data from the server to determine how to ask for the remaining portion of the file. If for whatever reason the specific restart point can't be located the browser will just ask for the full file again.

Interestingly enough, when pulling down mp3 files IE was happy to let me pause, but never restarted correctly (Chrome did), but when I pulled down a zip file IE wouldn't even enable the Pause button (again, Chrome did and it worked fine).

As @siva.k points out the Azure BLOB API (both REST and SDKs) support requesting block ranges so in theory the Storage system itself supports not only resume but partial retrievals of any type.